# SQL JOIN one way or the other way

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Is it possible to execute another JOIN query when the first returns NULL?
For e.g.:

```
SELECT 
    tr.TripId,
    mvP.MovementId as FirstMovementId,
FROM
    [dbo].[Trips] AS tr 
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
            mvP.TripId,
            mvP.MovementId,
            mvP.PickUp_PlannedTime,
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (
                PARTITION BY 
                    mvP.TripId 
                ORDER BY 
                    mvP.PickUp_PlannedTime,
                    mvP.PickUp_Sequence,
                    mvP.MovementId
            ) AS RNK
        FROM 
            [dbo].[Movements] AS mvP
        WHERE 
            mvP.Deleted = 0 AND COALESCE (mvP.AbsenceStateName, 'Available') = 'Available'

     LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT 
                mvP.TripId,
                mvP.MovementId,
                mvP.PickUp_PlannedTime,
                DENSE_RANK() OVER (
                    PARTITION BY 
                        mvP.TripId 
                    ORDER BY 
                        mvP.PickUp_PlannedTime,
                        mvP.PickUp_Sequence,
                        mvP.MovementId
                ) AS RNK
            FROM 
                [dbo].[Movements] AS mvP
            WHERE 
                mvP.Deleted = 0
            ) mvP ON mvP.TripId = tr.TripId AND mvP.RNK = 1
       WHERE tr.Deleted = 0
```

To be more precisely. I would like the 2nd JOIN to fill up the possible NULL the first JOIN could return. I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

Comment: You mean like a UNION of the two JOINS?    Or maybe a COALESCE?

Comment: This is not a valid SELECT, the last two lines don't match. How many rows are returned by the first join, more than 1? If it's a single row it seems like you can combine both Derived Tables into one by modifying the RANK, as the only difference is the WHERE-condition: RANK() OVER (
PARTITION BY 
mvP.TripId 
ORDER BY 
**CASE WHEN COALESCE (mvP.AbsenceStateName, 'Available') = 'Available' THEN 0 ELSE 1 end,**
mvP.PickUp_PlannedTime,
mvP.PickUp_Sequence,
mvP.MovementId
) AS RNK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you would just use `coalesce()` in the outer `select:

```
SELECT tr.TripId,
       COALESCE(mvP1.MovementId, mvp2.Movementid) as FirstMovementId,
```

Comment: Almost there, but the second join might still increase the number of result-columns even if there are matching entries in the first joined table - so you'd either have to add a bit to the second join-condition or use `DISTINCT` or be sure that there will be at most one match in the second joined table.

Comment: I guess it could be that easy... Is it possible to only perform the second join if the first returned NULL?

Comment: @Michael90 . . . Not in SQL.  There is actually a way you could sequentialize the operations using a `case` statement and subqueries.  However, it is easier to optimize the full query.  I do think there might be a way to combine the two subqueries (they look similar), but the question doesn't explain the logic and that would need to be done very carefully.

Answer (score 0):

You may join the 2 sub queries at the same time and use the isnull (SQL SERVER) or NVL(Oracle) function to pick the right one. I assume the tripId is the field to make the join.

```
SELECT 
    tr.TripId,
    isnull(mvPav.MovementId, mvPdel.MovementId) as FirstMovementId,
FROM
    [dbo].[Trips] AS tr 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT 
            mvP.TripId,
            mvP.MovementId,
            mvP.PickUp_PlannedTime,
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (
                PARTITION BY 
                    mvP.TripId 
                ORDER BY 
                    mvP.PickUp_PlannedTime,
                    mvP.PickUp_Sequence,
                    mvP.MovementId
            ) AS RNK
        FROM 
            [dbo].[Movements] AS mvP
        WHERE 
            mvP.Deleted = 0 AND COALESCE (mvP.AbsenceStateName, 'Available') = 'Available') AS mvPav on tr.TripId = mvPav.TripId
     LEFT OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT 
                mvP.TripId,
                mvP.MovementId,
                mvP.PickUp_PlannedTime,
                DENSE_RANK() OVER (
                    PARTITION BY 
                        mvP.TripId 
                    ORDER BY 
                        mvP.PickUp_PlannedTime,
                        mvP.PickUp_Sequence,
                        mvP.MovementId
                ) AS RNK
            FROM 
                [dbo].[Movements] AS mvP
            WHERE 
                mvP.Deleted = 0
            ) mvP ON mvP.TripId = tr.TripId AND mvP.RNK = 1
       WHERE tr.Deleted = 0) as mvPdel ON tr.TripId = mvPdel.TripId
```